# A query which excludes certain IDs but includes all others (including nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm logging all impressions of a certain page, by saving each visit as a record in `Impression`.

`Impression` saves the `user_id` if the visitor is logged in, hence some records have no user_id saved.

When querying the log to display number of visits I want to exclude the admins of the site.

The following is one way to exclude the admins, but it doesn't include records with no user_id atribute:

```
Impression.where("user_id NOT IN (?)", [1,2])
```

**How can I, in Rails 3.2, do a query which excludes records with certain (multiple) attribute values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Impression.where("user_id is null OR user_id NOT IN (?)", [1,2])`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Impression.where("user_id is not null and user_id NOT IN (?)", [1,2])
```

Comment: Sorry, it should be like this: Impression.where("user_id is not null and user_id NOT IN (?)", [1,2])

Comment: I want to include records as well which doesn not have the user_id set, i guess `is not null` is doing the inverse?

Comment: What do you mean "which doesn not have the user_id set"? Don't want the user_id column exists in the query result?

Comment: The `Impression` model have, among others, an `user_id` attribute. Sometimes this attribute exists (logged in user), sometimes not (not logged in user). I want ALL records to be included in the query result, EXCEPT for when the user_id is either `1` or `2`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally confused... Is user_id a column in impressions table? How do you make records when the user is not logged in?